# Jetty IOException never thrown

Tags: java, exception, jetty

i am having the following snippet

```
try {
    client.send(exchange);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //handle exception here
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

where client is an org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient client and i am sending a message to a NON working host expecting to catch a refused exception (or any other kind) but it seems impossible to handle it.

Are there any workarounds for that?

Comment: try catching it with Exception e. once it catches it gives you the exception class which caught it. then you can use the specific one.

Comment: that didn't work either. The solution was to override onConnectionFailed(Throwable x) but thank you for your time ;)